# For loop does not run within function declaration in Shell

Tags: linux, shell, unix, for-loop

My for loop is not running within shell when the function end_process is executed. Similar for loops run outside of a function declaration. I'm wondering why it doesn't run or how to make it run.

```
function end_process {

    {
    echo "stopped on $(date)"
    echo "$arguments_line"
    echo "$invalid_arguments_line"
    } >> spy.log

    for ((i=0; i<counter; i++)); do
            echo "${usernames[$i]}" >> spy.log
            echo "test line"
    done
    echo "007 Signing Out"
    exit 0
}
```

I'm using bash

#!/bin/bash

Also tried this

```
function end_process {

    {
    echo "stopped on $(date)"
    echo "$arguments_line"
    echo "$invalid_arguments_line"
    } >> spy.log

    for i in `seq 0 $counter`
    do
    #for ((i=0; i<counter; i++)); do
            echo "i is $i"
            echo "${usernames[$i]}" >> spy.log
            echo "test line"
    done
    echo "007 Signing Out"
    exit 0
 }
```

but neither worked

Comment: Could you specify which shell? Also I suspect the last `;` in `for ((i=0; i<counter; i++)); do` might have something to do with it.

Comment: What is the value of `counter`?  It is not set in the code you show.

Comment: counter is the size of the array (usernames) + 1. Do I need to pass it into the function?

Answer (score 0):

Problem was that I was calling the function

```
trap end_process SIGUSR1
```

but we need to put in escape strings for the function name

```
trap 'end_process' SIGUSR1
```

I guess this was just a common problem with RTFM